# Remove objects from ArrayList?

Tags: android

I have one ListView, it contains check boxes. By default all check boxes are checked, if we uncheck any check box the position will be added to mCheckedArrayList. Now I want remove all unchecked positions from the Listview. I used the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<=mCheckedArrayList.size;i++){
    int removePosition=mCheckedArrayList.get(i);
    mDisplayArrayList.remove(removePosition);
}
```

But it is giving an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: post your full code. And can't understand your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are removing objects in the wrong order. You should always reverse the order of the loop if you are removing elements within the loop:

```
for(int i = mCheckedArrayList.size()-1 ; i >= 0; i--){
    mDisplayArrayList.remove(mCheckedArrayList.get(i));
}
```

As a side note, if you wanted to loop through front first (in cases where you are not deleting elements), you would have to change your loop end condition to the following:

```
i < mCheckedArrayList.size()
```

Thanks to Martín for the comment. To be aware of modifications you could always use a 'final ref' of the array.

```
final ArrayList<T> arrayListToBeUsed = mCheckedArrayList;
for(int i = arrayListToBeUsed .size()-1 ; i >= 0; i--){
    arrayListToBeUsed .remove(arrayListToBeUsed .get(i));
}
```

Comment: Great answer, just one thing, I cant understand where the -1 to the arraylist size came from, thanks.

Comment: the top index is size-1 because indexes start at 0 in Java

Comment: @Moss Great Work sir. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No need to take any iterator. No need to loop your list to remove objects from list.

Following line will simply remove all objects from arraylist and makes it empty.

```
myArrayList.clear();
```

Comment: it will remove elements or will set them to null?

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view using iterators is most correct part

```
ListIterator<Object> listIterator = mCheckedArray.listIterator();       
    for(;listIterator.hasNext() ; listIterator.next()){ 
        listIterator.remove();
    }
```

It'll also prevents another thread from injecting objects into yours collection

Answer (score 0):

Try changing '<=' in your for loop to '<'.

Answer (score 0):

In programming, first item start at 0, last item is at the size minus 1.

```
for(int i=0;i<=mCheckedArrayList.size;i++){ // <-- remove '='
```